# What am I doing wrong in scoping my function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this test case, I am using append.child with plain JavaScript to add 3 kinds of divs (blue, red, green) to a parent multiple times according to their corresponding button onclicks, then I am adding another child inside the added div with another button (innerButton).

My issue is that, the onclick function which is assigned to the innerbutton and is nested within the initial function, listens only to the very first appended div, and it adds the input (which is supposed to be added to the div I'm clicking on) to the last append element of its 'kind'.
I am doing something wrong with my scoping but I can't see it.
I just started studying JavaScript, so I am not familiar yet with libraries, jQuery etc.

```js
var countBlue = 0;
var countRed = 0;
var countGreen = 0;

function addBlue() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var blue = document.createElement("div");

  blue.id = "blueDiv";
  blue.innerHTML = "<input id=blueInput><button id=innerButtonBlue onclick=addInputs()>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(blue);

  document.getElementById("innerButtonBlue").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    blue.appendChild(newInput);
  }

  countBlue++;
}

function addRed() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var red = document.createElement("div");

  red.id = "redDiv";
  red.innerHTML = "<input id=redInput><button id=innerButtonRed>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(red);

  document.getElementById("innerButtonRed").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    red.appendChild(newInput);
  }

  countRed++;

}

function addGreen() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var green = document.createElement("div");

  green.id = "greenDiv";
  green.innerHTML = "<input id=greenInput><button id=innerButtonGreen>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(green)

  document.getElementById("innerButtonGreen").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input id="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    green.appendChild(newInput);
  }
  countGreen++;
}

function displayCounters() {
  alert("Blue divs amount : " + parseInt(countBlue) + "\n" + " Red divs amount : " + parseInt(countRed) + "\n" + " Green divs amount : " + parseInt(countGreen) + "\n" + "\n" + " All together is : " + (parseInt(countBlue) + parseInt(countRed) + parseInt(countGreen)))
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#blueDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

#redDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

#greenDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

#innerButtonRed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#innerButtonBlue {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#innerButtonGreen {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#newInput {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 162px;
  height: 23px;
}

#redInput {
  background: red;
}

#blueInput {
  background: blue;
}

#greenInput {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  <button onclick="addBlue()">BLUE</button>
  <button onclick="addRed()">RED</button>
  <button onclick="addGreen()">GREEN</button>
  <button onclick="displayCounters()">COUNTERS</button>
  <div id="div1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: issue with button id for the new fields you generate they all have same id

Comment: ok, should i try and give them a different id every time i call the addColor function?

Comment: Having same id is bad html will cause bad behaviour

Comment: According to spec getElementById will return first element it finds with that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that, although you can technically add the same id to multiple elements, it is bad practice to do so. The id of an element should be [unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). If you need to apply the same style or target multiple elements with your code you should use [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead of id.
I think that's what is causing issues in your code.

Second, since you say you are learning, i think it would be good if you tried to make a single function to add the elements since the code is repeated in all of the three functions, except for the color.
Try making the function accept the color as a variable so you can reuse it for the three colors. Imagine if it was a hundred colors.

```js
var countBlue = 0;
var countRed = 0;
var countGreen = 0;

function addBlue() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  countBlue++; //set the counter to one so ids don't start at zero
  
  div.id = `blueDiv-${countBlue}`; //creates a unique id depending on the counter
  div.classList = "blueDiv";
  div.innerHTML = `<input id="blueInput-${countBlue}" class="blueInput"><button id="innerButtonBlue-${countBlue}" onclick="addInputs">ADD INPUTS</button>`;
  addTo.appendChild(div);

  document.getElementById(`innerButtonBlue-${countBlue}`).onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = `<input id="newInput-blue-${countBlue}" class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">`;
    div.appendChild(newInput);
  }
}

function addRed() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  countRed++
  
  div.id = `redDiv-${countRed}`;
  div.classList = "redDiv";
  div.innerHTML = `<input id="redInput-${countRed}" class="redInput"><button id="innerButtonRed-${countRed}" onclick="addInputs">ADD INPUTS</button>`;
  addTo.appendChild(div);

  document.getElementById(`innerButtonRed-${countRed}`).onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = `<input id="newInput-red-${countRed}" class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">`;
    div.appendChild(newInput);
  }
}

function addGreen() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  countGreen++
  
  div.id = `greenDiv-${countGreen}`; 
  div.classList = "greenDiv";
  div.innerHTML = `<input id="greenInput-${countGreen}" class="greenInput"><button id="innerButtonGreen-${countGreen}" onclick="addInputs">ADD INPUTS</button>`;
  addTo.appendChild(div);

  document.getElementById(`innerButtonGreen-${countGreen}`).onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = `<input id="newInput-green-${countGreen}" class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">`;
    div.appendChild(newInput);
  }
}

function displayCounters() {
  alert("Blue divs amount : " + parseInt(countBlue) + "\n" + " Red divs amount : " + parseInt(countRed) + "\n" + " Green divs amount : " + parseInt(countGreen) + "\n" + "\n" + " All together is : " + (parseInt(countBlue) + parseInt(countRed) + parseInt(countGreen)))
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blueDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.redDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.greenDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

.innerButtonRed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.innerButtonBlue {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.innerButtonGreen {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.newInput {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 162px;
  height: 23px;
}

.redInput {
  background: red;
}

.blueInput {
  background: blue;
}

.greenInput {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addBlue()">BLUE</button>
<button onclick="addRed()">RED</button>
<button onclick="addGreen()">GREEN</button>
<button onclick="displayCounters()">COUNTERS</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: thank man,i appreciate it. as i said in the above answer i just started so I'm trying to write simple code for now in order develop some better understanding in js before i dive into more complex concepts,do you know any good and comprehensive source to learn how to simplify my coding?

Comment: @VaggelisNos in keeping with your question, I would first look into DRY (don't repeat yourself) code definition. That was why I suggested you rewrite the functions addGreen, addBlue and addRed.
I don't really know what to suggest in terms of the best sources to learn. I can only recommend the ones I used: Javascript The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford, Javascript and jQuery by Joan Duckett and seem like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique in the whole document. Don't use IDs for this, you can just use a class. But even with a class how is the code supposed to know which element it should look for since there will be more than one existing with the class? The solution is to search only inside the element that you just created (e.g. `blue.querySelector('.someClass')` to search for the first element with class `someClass` inside the `blue` element).

I changed your code to use classes everywhere:

```js
var countBlue = 0;
var countRed = 0;
var countGreen = 0;

function addBlue() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var blue = document.createElement("div");

  blue.className = "blueDiv";
  blue.innerHTML = "<input class='firstInput'><button class='innerButton'>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(blue);

  blue.querySelector(".innerButton").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    blue.appendChild(newInput);
  }

  countBlue++;
}

function addRed() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var red = document.createElement("div");

  red.className = "redDiv";
  red.innerHTML = "<input class='firstInput'><button class='innerButton'>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(red);

  red.querySelector(".innerButton").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    red.appendChild(newInput);
  }

  countRed++;

}

function addGreen() {
  var addTo = document.getElementById('div1')
  var green = document.createElement("div");

  green.className = "greenDiv";
  green.innerHTML = "<input class='firstInput'><button class='innerButton'>ADD INPUTS</button>";
  addTo.appendChild(green)

  green.querySelector(".innerButton").onclick = function() {
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = '<input class="newInput" placeholder="NEW">';
    green.appendChild(newInput);
  }
  countGreen++;
}

function displayCounters() {
  alert("Blue divs amount : " + parseInt(countBlue) + "\n" + " Red divs amount : " + parseInt(countRed) + "\n" + " Green divs amount : " + parseInt(countGreen) + "\n" + "\n" + " All together is : " + (parseInt(countBlue) + parseInt(countRed) + parseInt(countGreen)))
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blueDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.redDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.greenDiv {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

.redDiv .innerButton {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.blueDiv .innerButton {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.greenDiv .innerButton {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.newInput {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 162px;
  height: 23px;
}

.redDiv .firstInput {
  background: red;
}

.blueDiv .firstInput {
  background: blue;
}

.greenDiv .firstInput {
  background: green;
}

body {
  height: 800px; /* Just for visibility here in Stack Overflow */
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  <button onclick="addBlue()">BLUE</button>
  <button onclick="addRed()">RED</button>
  <button onclick="addGreen()">GREEN</button>
  <button onclick="displayCounters()">COUNTERS</button>
  <div id="div1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

There is a lot more that could be improved of course - the code duplication could be removed, a generalized function for all three types (red/green/blue) can be created that is differentiated just by an attribute on the button for example - but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: wow, thanks man. i know, i just started and i keep things simple for the moment,in order to understand everything im doing before i dive into more complex practices. any good source on how to simplify my code?